# Watson Discovery Service - Query Data collection Node.js - passage missing

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson, watson, discovery

I run a query to the a response from Watson Discovery Service and I would like to include the passages in my response (by default the passages are not include, using passages = true should include it. But I don't
get it.

```
var queryString = {'natural_language_query':searchString};
                insert(cloudantDb,"9", "Call freie Textsuche ",       queryString, "-",  params);                    

                return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
                    discovery.query({
                        environment_id: 'my env id',
                        collection_id: 'my coll id',
                        query: queryString,
                        passages: true,
                        count: 3

                    }
```

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to set the passages inside the [queryoptions](https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/discovery-v1#!/Queries/query) parameter, like this API reference for test seems.

```
var queryOptions = {'natural_language_query':searchString, 'passages': true};
```

**Try to see the cURL example using this parameter:**

```
curl -u "{username}":"{password}" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/{environment_id}/collections/{collection_id}/query?version=2017-06-25&natural_language_query='collie'&passages=true"
```

This [part](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/discovery/query-reference.html#structure-parameters) of Official documentation talking about this [parameter](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/blob/master/discovery/v1.js#L663) in line #663.

**Note:** The passages parameter is supported only on *private* collections. It is not supported in the Watson Discovery News collection. You cannot use `natural_language_query` and the `query` parameter in the same **query options**.